# Get ID from array, store it and remove it locally

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am building an an Angular/Javascript/Ionic/Cordova App.

I have a function where I call the below array which is stored as a variable (existingEntries)

```
categories: Array [276]
 [0...99]
   0: Object
     id: 288
     exclude: false   
   1: Object
     id: 320
     exclude: true
```

This function crawls all of the elements in that array to see if the value exclude is set to true or false

```
    var existingEntries = $scope.categoryList;
    if(existingEntries == null) existingEntries = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < existingEntries.length; i++) {
            if (existingEntries[i]['exclude'] == true) {
                $scope.addLocalExcludedCategories(i);
            } else if (existingEntries[i]['exclude'] == false) {
                $scope.removeLocalExcludedCategories(i);
            }                       
    }
```

Once this is done the other relative functions (addLocal.. and remove Local...) are called to store the id's. Below is the addLocal.. function and this works but I am getting duplicates when I run this code over and over and I am sure it can be coded better. I am using localstorage as I need the array to be saved locally but if you have other solutions would be great.

```
    $scope.addLocalExcludedCategories = function(catID) {
    console.log("addLocalExcludedCategories Called")
    //Add Item to Excluded Categories Variable
    var existingEntries = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("ExcludedCategories"));                            
    if(existingEntries == null) existingEntries = [];

    var entryId = catID;
    var entry = {
        'id': entryId,
    };
    existingEntries.push(entry);        

    window.localStorage.setItem("ExcludedCategories", JSON.stringify(existingEntries));
    $scope.ExcludedCategories = window.localStorage.getItem("ExcludedCategories");      
}
```

Also here is the remove function which is not working as expected as I am finding id's which have the exclude value set to true and not false.

```
$scope.removeLocalExcludedCategories = function(catID) {    
console.log("removeLocalExcludedCategories Called")
    //Remove Item to Excluded Categories Variable
    var existingEntries = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("ExcludedCategories"));
    if(existingEntries == null) existingEntries = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < existingEntries.length; i++) {
        if (existingEntries[i]['id'] == catID) {
            console.log(i);
            existingEntries.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    //console.log("Remove Categories >>>");
    //console.log(existingEntries);
    window.localStorage.setItem("ExcludedCategories", JSON.stringify(existingEntries));
    $scope.ExcludedCategories = window.localStorage.getItem("ExcludedCategories");
    console.log($scope.ExcludedCategories);
}
```

Hope this makes sense and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking if there are already entries exist in **existingEntries** Array and that's why you are getting dupes
  **Try this code...**

```
$scope.addLocalExcludedCategories = function(catID) {
    console.log("addLocalExcludedCategories Called")
    //Add Item to Excluded Categories Variable
    var existingEntries = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("ExcludedCategories")) || [];

    var entryId = catID;
    var entry = {
        'id': entryId,
    };
    if(existingEntries.length > 0){
    existingEntries.forEach(function(entry){
     if(entry.id !== entry.id){
      existingEntries.push(entry); 
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with an ng-if statement and by storing the array locally then parsing it on call.

```
$scope.ifCatExcludedTerms = function(sent_id){
    var doesNotExist = true;
    arraytosearch = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("categoryListMem"));
    //console.log (sent_id);
        for (var i = 0; i < arraytosearch.length; i++) {
            if (arraytosearch[i]['id'] == sent_id) {
                doesNotExist = false;
            }
        }
    return doesNotExist;
}
```